# Want to find Year on Year calculation using Groupby and apply for various years

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
    MARKET     PRODUCT  TIMEPERIOD  DATE    VALUES
0   USA MARKET  APPLE   QUARTER 2020-06-01  100
1   USA MARKET  APPLE   YEARLY  2020-06-01  1000
2   USA MARKET  PEAR    QUARTER 2020-06-01  200
3   USA MARKET  PEAR    YEARLY  2020-06-01  5000
4   USA MARKET  APPLE   QUARTER 2019-06-01  300
5   USA MARKET  PEAR    YEARLY  2019-06-01  2000
6   USA MARKET  PEAR    QUARTER 2019-06-01  100
7   USA MARKET  PEAR    YEARLY  2019-06-01  3000
8   USA MARKET  APPLE   QUARTER 2018-06-01  300
9   USA MARKET  PEAR    YEARLY  2018-06-01  2000
10  USA MARKET  PEAR    QUARTER 2018-06-01  100
11  USA MARKET  PEAR    YEARLY  2018-06-01  3000
12  UK MARKET   WATERMELON  QUARTER 2020-06-01  200
13  UK MARKET   WATERMELON  YEARLY  2020-06-01  5000
14  UK MARKET   GRAPE   QUARTER 2020-06-01  200
15  UK MARKET   GRAPE   YEARLY  2020-06-01  5000
16  UK MARKET   WATERMELON  QUARTER 2019-06-01  500
17  UK MARKET   WATERMELON  YEARLY  2019-06-01  300
18  UK MARKET   GRAPE   QUARTER 2019-06-01  50
19  UK MARKET   GRAPE   YEARLY  2019-06-01  500
20  UK MARKET   WATERMELON  QUARTER 2018-06-01  500
21  UK MARKET   WATERMELON  YEARLY  2018-06-01  300
22  UK MARKET   GRAPE   QUARTER 2018-06-01  50
23  UK MARKET   GRAPE   YEARLY  2018-06-01  500
```

I want to find the Year on Year difference of each product in each market for each timeperiod (that's a mouthful!) For example, for product APPLE in USA MARKET during the TIMEPERIOD Quarter, the 2020-06-01 growth rate is simply (100-300)/300 = 66.6% where I used the values of 2020-06-01 minus 2019-06-01 divided by 2019-06-01.

As you can see, the problem with the below code is that it only returns the growth rate of the current year vs the past year. And ignores the past year 2019 vs 2018. I have tried a few `if-else` blocks, but all seem to point to some errors, would appreciate it if there are any neat solutions to resolve this. In short, my `growth_rate_prev` is unused here (although I did try to weave it in but it failed).

```
def year_on_year(df):    
    try:
        curr_year_val = df[df['DATE']==max(df['DATE'])]['VALUES'].sum() 
        prev_year_val = df[df['DATE']==(max(df['DATE'])-relativedelta(months=12))]['VALUES'].sum()
        prev_prev_year_val = df[df['DATE']==(df(df['DATE'])-relativedelta(months=24))]['VALUES'].sum()
        
        growth_rate_curr = ((curr_year_val)-(prev_year_val))/(prev_year_val)
        growth_rate_prev = ((prev_year_val)-(prev_prev_year_val))/(prev_prev_year_val)
        
        
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        growth_rate_curr, growth_rate_prev = 0 , 0

        
    return growth_rate_curr


    
def product_growth(applied_group_df):            
        applied_group_df['Year on Year difference'] = year_on_year(applied_group_df)
        return applied_group_df

growth_rate_df = df_2.groupby(["TIMEPERIOD",'MARKET', 'PRODUCT']).apply(product_growth)
```

In case anyone wants to reproduce the code, you can create the df by using the code below:

```
df_list_for_yoy = [['USA MARKET', 'APPLE', 'QUARTER', '2020-06-01', 100], ['USA MARKET', 'APPLE', 'YEARLY', '2020-06-01', 1000],
           ['USA MARKET', 'PEAR', 'QUARTER', '2020-06-01', 200],  ['USA MARKET', 'PEAR', 'YEARLY', '2020-06-01', 5000], 
           ['USA MARKET', 'APPLE', 'QUARTER', '2019-06-01', 300],  ['USA MARKET', 'APPLE', 'YEARLY', '2019-06-01', 2000],
           ['USA MARKET', 'PEAR', 'QUARTER', '2019-06-01', 100],  ['USA MARKET', 'PEAR', 'YEARLY', '2019-06-01', 3000],
           ['USA MARKET', 'APPLE', 'QUARTER', '2018-06-01', 300],  ['USA MARKET', 'APPLE', 'YEARLY', '2018-06-01', 2000],
           ['USA MARKET', 'PEAR', 'QUARTER', '2018-06-01', 100],  ['USA MARKET', 'PEAR', 'YEARLY', '2018-06-01', 3000],
           ['UK MARKET', 'WATERMELON', 'QUARTER', '2020-06-01', 200],  ['UK MARKET', 'WATERMELON', 'YEARLY', '2020-06-01', 5000], 
           ['UK MARKET', 'GRAPE', 'QUARTER', '2020-06-01', 200],    ['UK MARKET', 'GRAPE', 'YEARLY', '2020-06-01', 5000],
           ['UK MARKET', 'WATERMELON', 'QUARTER', '2019-06-01', 500],  ['UK MARKET', 'WATERMELON', 'YEARLY', '2019-06-01', 300], 
           ['UK MARKET', 'GRAPE', 'QUARTER', '2019-06-01', 50],    ['UK MARKET', 'GRAPE', 'YEARLY', '2019-06-01', 500],
           ['UK MARKET', 'WATERMELON', 'QUARTER', '2018-06-01', 500],  ['UK MARKET', 'WATERMELON', 'YEARLY', '2018-06-01', 300], 
           ['UK MARKET', 'GRAPE', 'QUARTER', '2018-06-01', 50],    ['UK MARKET', 'GRAPE', 'YEARLY', '2018-06-01', 500]]

column_names = ['MARKET', 'PRODUCT', 'TIMEPERIOD', 'DATE', 'VALUES']
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df_list_for_yoy, columns = column_names)
df_2['DATE']= pd.to_datetime(df_2['DATE'])
```

Comment: Just to note: `(100-300)/300` equals to a "negative growth" of ~66.6%.

Comment: Should we assume that the dataframe only has 2020, 2019 and 2018 values or could it have more?

Comment: @sharathnatraj It could have more, in my real data it has up until 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to get the year-year combination, together with further manipulation inside a function to be applied in the groups, like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

def get_annual_growth(grp):
    # Get all possible combination of the years from dataset
    year_comb_lists = np.sort([sorted(comb) for comb in combinations(grp.DATE.dt.year, 2)])
    # Remove those combinations in which difference is greather than 1 (for example, 2018-2020)
    year_comb_lists = year_comb_lists[(np.diff(year_comb_lists) == 1).flatten()] # comment this line if it's not the case
    # Get year-combination labels
    year_comb_strings = ['-'.join(map(str, comb)) for comb in year_comb_lists]
    
    # Create sub-dataframe with to be concated afterwards by pandas `groupby`
    subdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Annual Reference', 'Annual Growth (%)'])
    for i,years in enumerate(year_comb_lists): # for each year combination ...
        actual_value, last_value = grp[grp.DATE.dt.year==years[1]].VALUES.mean(), grp[grp.DATE.dt.year==years[0]].VALUES.mean()
        growth = (actual_value - last_value) / last_value # calculate the annual growth
        subdf.loc[i, :] = [year_comb_strings[i], growth] 
    return subdf

df_2.groupby(['TIMEPERIOD','MARKET', 'PRODUCT']).apply(get_annual_growth)
```

Output:

```
                                   Annual Reference Annual Growth (%)
TIMEPERIOD MARKET     PRODUCT                                        
QUARTER    UK MARKET  GRAPE      0        2019-2020               300
                                 1        2018-2019                 0
                      WATERMELON 0        2019-2020               -60
                                 1        2018-2019                 0
           USA MARKET APPLE      0        2019-2020            -66.67
                                 1        2018-2019                 0
                      PEAR       0        2019-2020               100
                                 1        2018-2019                 0
YEARLY     UK MARKET  GRAPE      0        2019-2020               900
                                 1        2018-2019                 0
                      WATERMELON 0        2019-2020           1566.67
                                 1        2018-2019                 0
           USA MARKET APPLE      0        2019-2020               -50
                                 1        2018-2019                 0
                      PEAR       0        2019-2020             66.67
                                 1        2018-2019                 0
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good too! Never get to use things from combinations

Comment: It's good because you don't have to bother about the combinations, it's escalable. btw, very interesting your problem! haha

Comment: Yes, an interesting problem indeed, something easily done in excel can be quite difficult in pandas. Actually I didn't quite get the 0, 1, 0, 1 columns yet

Comment: Just to clarify, the part where you wrote `VALUES.mean()`, the `mean()` is purely there to convert the series value to a float value right?

Comment: Not only to that. I don't know if you have more values per year in your full dataset. If your have just a single data per category like the date you provided, `.mean()` is doing nothing other than taking the value as is. But if you have more dates per category (for example, 2020-06-01 and 2020-10-01), it computes the mean. In such circumstances, it would be somewhat necessary to apply some aggregate function in order to provide an output like this one.

Comment: About the 0, 1 "columns", they're not about column indexes, they're the index from the years. Note that first I get the year-year combinations within an array with sorted lists, like these: `[[2019, 2020], [2018, 2019]]`. Then we iterate in each of these lists, where index 0 and 1 corresponds to the years 2019 and 2020 from the first sorted list, respectively.

Comment: I recommend analyze what each lines does separately. Pandas `groupby` just automatically subset the dataframe for us with the target-groups. We can simulate one of these groups with: `grp = df_2[(df_2.TIMEPERIOD=='QUARTER') & (df_2.MARKET=='USA MARKET') & (df_2.PRODUCT=='APPLE')]` so that `grp` represents a group. Then you can run each line from the function separately, verifying its output.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply, I went through your code line by line and made some changes in my own answer below. Please take a look if you will :)

Comment: Cool! Own modifications will be required. I'm glad you understood it well. Best.

Answer (score 1):

Please find this approach.

```
df = df_2.groupby(['MARKET','TIMEPERIOD','PRODUCT'])['VALUES'].apply(list).reset_index()
def func(x):
    year = 2021
    for i in range(1,len(x['VALUES'])):
        colname = str(year-i) + '-Growth'
        x[colname] = round(abs(x['VALUES'][i]- x['VALUES'][i-1])/x['VALUES'][i]*100,2)
    return x
df = df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1).drop('VALUES',axis=1)
print(df)
```

Its a generalized code which should work for all previous years dating back to 2013 as mentioned in the comment.

Prints:

```
       MARKET TIMEPERIOD     PRODUCT  2020-Growth  2019-Growth
0   UK MARKET    QUARTER       GRAPE       300.00          0.0
1   UK MARKET    QUARTER  WATERMELON        60.00          0.0
2   UK MARKET     YEARLY       GRAPE       900.00          0.0
3   UK MARKET     YEARLY  WATERMELON      1566.67          0.0
4  USA MARKET    QUARTER       APPLE        66.67          0.0
5  USA MARKET    QUARTER        PEAR       100.00          0.0
6  USA MARKET     YEARLY       APPLE        50.00          0.0
7  USA MARKET     YEARLY        PEAR        66.67          0.0
```

Explanation:

First, I do a group by on the values and put it into a list:

```
df_2.groupby(['MARKET','TIMEPERIOD','PRODUCT'])['VALUES'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

for e.g

```
       MARKET TIMEPERIOD     PRODUCT              VALUES
0   UK MARKET    QUARTER       GRAPE       [200, 50, 50]
1   UK MARKET    QUARTER  WATERMELON     [200, 500, 500]
....
```

Then, I write an apply to loop through the 'VALUES' list column and do the growth calculation.

Comment: Seems good, but do you think we should also groupby Market

Comment: Yeah, that is right. I forgot that you wanted this by  'MARKET' also. You can just add 'MARKET' to groupby as you mentoned.

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to [Caina Max's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7076819/cain%C3%A3-max-couto-silva) to accommodate to my real data, where there are various months in a year. There can be 2020-06-01, 2020-03-01, 2019-12-01 etc and hence I have to make the below changes to get the combination pairs of the dates who are 1 year apart exactly, namely, [2019-06-01, 2020-06-01], [2019-03-01, 2020-03-01], [2018-12-01, 2019-12-01] etc etc.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

def get_annual_growth(grp):
    # Get all possible combination of the years from dataset
    year_comb_lists = np.sort([sorted(comb) for comb in combinations(grp.DATE, 2)])
    new_year_comb_lists = [comb_dates for comb_dates in year_comb_lists if comb_dates[0]==comb_dates[1]-relativedelta(months=12)]

    # Get year-combination labels
    year_comb_strings = [comb[1] for comb in new_year_comb_lists]
    
    # Create sub-dataframe with to be concated afterwards by pandas `groupby`
    subdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Annual Reference', 'Annual Growth (%)'])
    for i,years in enumerate(new_year_comb_lists ): # for each year combination ...
        actual_value, last_value = grp[grp['Date']==years[1]].Values.mean(), grp[grp['Date']==years[0]].Values.mean()
        growth = (actual_value - last_value) / last_value # calculate the annual growth
        subdf.loc[i, :] = [year_comb_strings[i], growth] 
    return subdf

df_2.groupby(['TIMEPERIOD','MARKET', 'PRODUCT']).apply(get_annual_growth)
df_2= df_2.reset_index()
df_2['Annual_Reference'] = pd.to_datetime(df_2['Annual_Reference'])
```

Comment: Good! Although I think you'll need to loop through `new_year_comb_lists` instead of `year_comb_lists` in order to work, since you created `year_comb_strings` based on that.