# Want to find Year on Year AND Quarter on Quarter calculation in one function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, apply

This is a continuation of the question I posted [here yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64852675/want-to-find-year-on-year-calculation-using-groupby-and-apply-for-various-years/). The answer was amazing but soon ran into a problem, because I also want the Quarter on Quarter calculations using the same logic.

*The dataframe is as follows, don't mind the length, I don't really know how to hide it (would appreciate if someone can enlighten me on how to hide long df...*

For there are some modifications, let me explain the problem once more. I want to find the Year on Year difference of each **Product** in each **Market** for each **Timeperiod** (that's a mouthful!) For example, for product **A** in **USA** MARKET during the TIMEPERIOD **QTR** with **Date 2020-06-01**, it has a **Value 100**. This merely means that during quarter 2 of 2020, we made a revenue of 100 dollars. I wish to find the growth rate of quarter 2 of 2020 as compared to quarter 2 of 2019, therefore the growth rate is simply **(100-300)/300 = -66.6%**. The same logic goes for the **Timeperiod MAT (Moving Annual Total)** when you want to calculate year on year growth.

Now I want to find the quarter on quarter growth as well, now take note that this calculation will not be relevant for the **Timeperiod MAT** and therefore my code below takes care of that (not sure if it's taken care of correctly). The output that my modified function works - but at the cost of readability in the output. Because now the for each row, the Annual Reference date does not match with the Quarterly Reference date. Because ultimately I need to use this output to do some analysis. Are there any improvements that can be made?

```
    MARKET  PRODUCT TIMEPERIOD  DATE        VALUES
0   USA     A       QTR         2018-06-01  300
1   USA     A       QTR         2019-06-01  300
2   USA     A       QTR         2020-03-01  100
3   USA     A       QTR         2020-06-01  100
4   USA     A       MAT         2018-06-01  2000
5   USA     A       MAT         2019-06-01  2000
6   USA     A       MAT         2020-06-01  1000
7   USA     B       QTR         2018-06-01  100
8   USA     B       QTR         2019-06-01  100
9   USA     B       QTR         2020-03-01  300
10  USA     B       QTR         2020-06-01  200
11  USA     B       MAT         2018-06-01  3000
12  USA     B       MAT         2019-06-01  3000
13  USA     B       MAT         2020-06-01  5000
14  UK      C       QTR         2018-06-01  500
15  UK      C       QTR         2019-06-01  500
16  UK      C       QTR         2020-03-01  200
17  UK      C       QTR         2020-06-01  200
18  UK      C       MAT         2018-06-01  300
19  UK      C       MAT         2019-06-01  300
20  UK      C       MAT         2020-06-01  5000
21  UK      D       QTR         2018-06-01  50
22  UK      D       QTR         2019-06-01  50
23  UK      D       QTR         2020-03-01  200
24  UK      D       QTR         2020-06-01  200
25  UK      D       MAT         2018-06-01  500
26  UK      D       MAT         2019-06-01  500
27  UK      D       MAT         2020-06-01  5000
```

My code below is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

def get_annual_growth(grp):
    # Get all possible combination of the years from dataset
    year_comb_lists = np.sort([sorted(comb) for comb in combinations(grp.Date, 2)])
    new_year_comb_lists = [comb_dates for comb_dates in year_comb_lists if comb_dates[0]==comb_dates[1]-relativedelta(months=12)]
    quarter_comb_lists = [comb_dates for comb_dates in year_comb_lists if comb_dates[0]==comb_dates[1]-relativedelta(months=3)]
    # Get year-combination labels
    year_comb_strings = [comb[1] for comb in new_year_comb_lists]
    quarter_comb_strings = [comb[1] for comb in quarter_comb_lists]

    # Create sub-dataframe with to be concated afterwards by pandas `groupby`
    subdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Annual_Reference', 'Annual_Growth', "Quarterly_Reference",'Quarterly_Growth'])
    for i,years in enumerate(new_year_comb_lists): # for each year combination ...
        actual_value, last_value = grp[grp['Date']==years[1]].Values.mean(), grp[grp['Date']==years[0]].Values.mean()
        growth = (actual_value - last_value) / last_value # calculate the annual growth
        subdf.loc[i, ['Annual_Reference', 'Annual_Growth']] = [year_comb_strings[i], growth] 
    for i, quarters in enumerate(quarter_comb_lists):
        actual_value, last_value = grp[grp['Date']==quarters[1]].Values.mean(), grp[grp['Date']==quarters[0]].Values.mean()
        growth = (actual_value - last_value) / last_value
        subdf.loc[i, ["Quarterly_Reference",'Quarterly_Growth']] = [quarter_comb_strings[i], growth] 
    return subdf

df_2.groupby(['TIMEPERIOD','MARKET', 'PRODUCT']).apply(get_annual_growth)
df_2= df_2.reset_index()
df_2['Annual_Reference'] = pd.to_datetime(df_2['Annual_Reference'])
df_2['Quarterly_Reference'] = pd.to_datetime(gr_products['Quarterly_Reference'])
```

For anyone who wants to reproduce the code, it is as below:

```
df_list = [['USA', 'A', 'QTR', '2020-06-01', 100], ['USA', 'A', 'MAT', '2020-06-01', 1000],
           ['USA', 'B', 'QTR', '2020-06-01', 200],  ['USA', 'B', 'MAT', '2020-06-01', 5000], 
           ['USA', 'A', 'QTR', '2020-03-01', 500], ['USA', 'B', 'QTR', '2020-03-01', 300],        
           ['USA', 'A', 'QTR', '2019-06-01', 300],  ['USA', 'A', 'MAT', '2019-06-01', 2000],
           ['USA', 'B', 'QTR', '2019-06-01', 100],  ['USA', 'B', 'MAT', '2019-06-01', 3000],
           ['USA', 'A', 'QTR', '2018-06-01', 300],  ['USA', 'A', 'MAT', '2018-06-01', 2000],
           ['USA', 'B', 'QTR', '2018-06-01', 100],  ['USA', 'B', 'MAT', '2018-06-01', 3000],
           ['UK', 'C', 'QTR', '2020-06-01', 200],  ['UK', 'C', 'MAT', '2020-06-01', 5000], 
           ['UK', 'C', 'QTR', '2020-03-01', 100],  ['UK', 'D', 'QTR', '2020-03-01', 50], 
           ['UK', 'D', 'QTR', '2020-06-01', 200],    ['UK', 'D', 'MAT', '2020-06-01', 5000],
           ['UK', 'C', 'QTR', '2019-06-01', 500],  ['UK', 'C', 'MAT', '2019-06-01', 300], 
           ['UK', 'D', 'QTR', '2019-06-01', 50],    ['UK', 'D', 'MAT', '2019-06-01', 500],
           ['UK', 'C', 'QTR', '2018-06-01', 500],  ['UK', 'C', 'MAT', '2018-06-01', 300], 
           ['UK', 'D', 'QTR', '2018-06-01', 50],    ['UK', 'D', 'MAT', '2018-06-01', 500]]

column_names = ['MARKET', 'PRODUCT', 'TIMEPERIOD', 'Date', 'Values']
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns = column_names)
df_2['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df_2['Date'])
df_2 = df_2.sort_values(by=['PRODUCT', 'TIMEPERIOD', 'Date']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df_2['month'] = df_2['Date'].dt.month
df_2['change'] = df_2.groupby(['MARKET','PRODUCT','TIMEPERIOD','month']).Values.pct_change()
```

It should work if you don't have any years of missing data.

Edit: The above is for year-on-year, for quarter-on-quarter don't group by month. Similarly, it should work if you don't have any quarters of missing data.

Comment: Great answer, although some cleanup is required, this is the easiest one to manipulate with!

Answer (score 0):

I found myself a way to make the output on the same Date level as follows, not the most elegant, but it works for now.

```
def get_annual_growth(grp):
    # The all possible combination from the years in dataset
    year_comb_lists = np.sort([sorted(comb) for comb in combinations(subset_group.Date, 2)])
    # Remove those combinations in which difference is greather than 1 (for example, 2018-2020)
    new_year_comb_lists = [comb_dates for comb_dates in year_comb_lists 
                           if comb_dates[0]==comb_dates[1]-relativedelta(months=12)]
    new_year_comb_lists=sorted(new_year_comb_lists,key=lambda x: x[1]) 
    quarter_comb_lists = [comb_dates for comb_dates in year_comb_lists 
                          if comb_dates[0]==comb_dates[1]-relativedelta(months=3)
                          and comb_dates[1].year != 2018]
    quarter_comb_lists=sorted(quarter_comb_lists, key=lambda x: x[1])
    # Get combination labels
    year_comb_strings = [comb[1] for comb in new_year_comb_lists]
    quarter_comb_strings = [comb[1] for comb in quarter_comb_lists]
    
    # Creat sub-dataframe with to be concated afterwards by pandas `groupby`
    subdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Annual_Reference', 'Annual_Growth', "Quarterly_Reference",'Quarterly_Growth'])

    for i , (years, quarters) in enumerate(zip(new_year_comb_lists, quarter_comb_lists)): # for each year combination ...
        try:
            curr_year_val, prev_year_val = grp[grp['Date']==years[1]].Values.mean(), grp[grp['Date']==years[0]].Values.mean()
            curr_qtr_val, prev_qtr_val = grp[grp['Date']==quarters[1]].Values.mean(), grp[grp['Date']==quarters[0]].Values.mean()
            year_gr = (curr_year_val - prev_year_val) / prev_year_val # calculate the annual growth
            qtr_gr = (curr_qtr_val - prev_qtr_val) / prev_qtr_val
            subdf.loc[i, ['Annual_Reference', 'Annual_Growth',
                          'Quarterly_Reference','Quarterly_Growth']] = [year_comb_strings[i], year_gr, quarter_comb_strings[i], qtr_gr] 
            
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            year_gr = 0
            qtr_gr = 0

    return subdf
```